# Error in ggqqplot "The following aesthetics were dropped during statistical transformation: sample"

Tags: r, ggpubr, aesthetics, qqplot

I am trying to use a QQ plot to determine if my data are normally distributed. I am using the `mtcars` dataset for practice. When making a QQ plot, I keep getting the error below:

```
Warning messages:
1: The following aesthetics were dropped during statistical transformation: sample
ℹ This can happen when ggplot fails to infer the correct grouping structure in the data.
ℹ Did you forget to specify a `group` aesthetic or to convert a numerical variable into a factor? 
2: The following aesthetics were dropped during statistical transformation: sample
ℹ This can happen when ggplot fails to infer the correct grouping structure in the data.
ℹ Did you forget to specify a `group` aesthetic or to convert a numerical variable into a factor?
```

The plot itself prints out, actually looks totally reasonable, and matches my output in Excel. However, I don't want to have this error message keep popping up as it's a bit annoying. I also worry I am missing something that could be important. Weirdly, when I run the examples listed on the help tab for `ggqqplot`, I get the same error. Does anyone know what might be going on? Here is my code for reference:

```
library("ggpubr")
ggqqplot(mtcars,x="mpg")
```

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. The code runs without errors or warnings. In any case, these are warnings rather than errors, and the plot is correct (it's the same as the one I get)

Comment: Hmm... odd! Thanks for checking I appreciate it.

Comment: I can recreate the problem. Could you post your sessionInfo(). I have ggpubr_0.4.0  ggplot2_3.4.0

Comment: Sorry all-- now I cannot reproduce the problem! I have absolutely no idea why I got the warning a few days ago, and why I don't have it now. I haven't installed any new versions of packages or changed my dataset. It's a mystery.